# Error when building ios application using fastlane remotely

Tags: ios, linux, macos, fastlane

i am trying to fix an error which i get when i try to ssh into mac-mini and run fastlane remotely.

The following build commands failed:

```
CodeSign /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<projectname>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<project>/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/<projectname>.appex

builtin-RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/ec2- 
user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<projectname>

Touch /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<projectname>

cd /Users/ec2-user/Documents/<projectname>
/usr/bin/touch -c /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<projectname>
```

Similar project runs and builds perfectly fine when i vnc into mac-mini and then run fastlane from mac-mini, the difference i noticed initialy was, it was asking me to specify keychain password, i did that and specifed always allow so it never asks me for password, but issue still persist if i ssh into mac-mini and run fastlane.

Any suggestions on this please.

Answer (score 0):

This command eventually worked for me and the issue was around unlocking the remote keychain before running fastlane build

Run below commands on remote server once ssh is complete

```
export KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD='your_keychain_passsword' 

sudo security unlock-keychain -p $KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

where **$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD**  holds the password for your keychain